# How do I disable Emmet's tab completion in Atom?

Tags: html, css, emmet, atom-editor

I want to use Emmet and Autocomplete-plus together, but Emmet's tab completion is overriding autocomplete-plus tab completion in CSS files.

For example, if I type

```
li
```

Autocomplete-plus gives me the option of `line-height`, which I highlight and then select by pressing tab, but Emmet prints out some other random rubbish instead.

Can I prevent Emmet from doing this in CSS files only?

Comment: From the settings of Autocomplete-plus you could change the key for selecting an autocomplete to enter. I don't believe Emmet has a similar option

Comment: Thanks AJ - I really want to use `tab` though, as it's so difficult to train myself to use another key.  I actually managed to find a solution which involved editing the keymap file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get this to work by adding this to the keymap.cson file:

```
# Stop emmet from hijacking tab from snippets and autocomplete
'atom-text-editor.autocomplete-active:not([mini])':
  'tab': 'autocomplete-plus:confirm'
```

Comment: Thank you for this hint... atom's key bindings are their own kind of hell. Its the last thing I want to waste my time with. Also, emmet's 'ctrl-e' can still be used after tab functionality has been rescued.

Answer (score 2):

I'm way late to this thread, but Atom now allows you to [disable a plugin's keybindings](https://github.com/atom/atom/pull/6245). I've disabled Emmet's keybindings and set my own:

```
'atom-text-editor:not([mini])':
    'cmd-shift-e': 'emmet:expand-abbreviation-with-tab'
```

Alternately, you could disable Emmet's keybindings, then enable the tab keybinding for HTML only:

```
'atom-text-editor[data-grammar="text html basic"]:not([mini])':
    'tab': 'emmet:expand-abbreviation-with-tab'
```

Comment: Are you on Windows? This unfortunately does not work for me. Any clues?

Comment: Try changing `cmd-shift-e` to `ctrl-shift-e`.

Comment: Had to set document syntax from PHP to HTML. Now it works. Heads up fellow coders. Document syntax needs to be **HTML**.

Comment: Though how to use Emmet when coding a WP theme that has PHP and HTML mixed? Either one or the other and keep changing document syntax? That can't be what Emmet devs had in mind..

Comment: Hm, not sure. On my editor, the cmd/ctrl-shift-e keybinding works regardless of the document syntax: PHP, plain text, etc.

Comment: Yeah ctrl-e works regardless of document syntax. Emmet is working on a fix for this. I wanted tab.